# Sine function guessing cognitive app

Tags: javascript, game, html, css, mathematics

Please help with improving this application. It is a guessing game, for learning the values of the sine function, and boosting brain power in the process.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Simplified Example with Buttons and Multiple of 15 Angles</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #angleDisplay {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <button id="refreshButton">Refresh</button>
  <button id="toggleButton">Toggle Angle Display</button>
  <p id="angleDisplay"></p>
  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawLine() {
      const angle = randomMultipleOf15(0, 24) * 15;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(
        canvas.width / 2 + (canvas.width / 3) * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180),
        canvas.height / 2 - (canvas.width / 3) * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
      );
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff1ac6";
      ctx.stroke();
      return { angle, sine: Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) };
    }

    function randomMultipleOf15(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    const refreshButton = document.getElementById("refreshButton");
    const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
    const angleDisplay = document.getElementById("angleDisplay");

    refreshButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const result = drawLine();
      angleDisplay.textContent = `Angle: ${result.angle} degrees, Sine: ${result.sine.toFixed(2)}`;
      if (angleDisplay.style.display === "block") {
        angleDisplay.style.display = "none";
        toggleButton.textContent = "Toggle Angle Display";
      }
    });

    toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (angleDisplay.style.display === "none" || angleDisplay.style.display === "") {
        angleDisplay.style.display = "block";
        toggleButton.textContent = "Toggle Angle Display (Hidden)";
      } else {
        angleDisplay.style.display = "none";
        toggleButton.textContent = "Toggle Angle Display";
      }
    });

    // Initial draw and display
    drawLine();
    angleDisplay.textContent = `Angle: ${drawLine().angle} degrees, Sine: ${drawLine().sine.toFixed(2)}`;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Sample output

[image: sample output]

Comment: It's unclear what a user is meant to do with this. Should toggling the angle display do anything? Code Review is for improving complete and working code. This seems incomplete.

Comment: @Sean the user sees a line at an angle, as if it was the hypotenuse of a unit circle, and they are to guess the angle, and the sine value. I can see that the app is not straightforward in this user experience aspect.

Comment: If you create future posts involving JS/HTML/CSS then it may be helpful to consider using [a stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), as the first answer does to provide a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following function is repetitive can be simplified:

```js
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (angleDisplay.style.display === "none" || angleDisplay.style.display === "") {
    angleDisplay.style.display = "block";
    toggleButton.textContent = "Toggle Angle Display (Hidden)";
  } else {
    angleDisplay.style.display = "none";
    toggleButton.textContent = "Toggle Angle Display";
  }
});
```

For one you can use `classList.toggle()` to add or remove a class from an element depending if the element already has that class or not.

Then you can use `classList.contains()` to check if an element has a class or not. That you can use within a ternary conditional operator to add the `(Hidden)` text to the button or not:

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('button');
const angleDisplay = document.querySelector('main');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  angleDisplay.classList.toggle('d-none');
  toggleButton.textContent = `Toggle Angle Display ${angleDisplay.classList.contains('d-none') ? '' : '(Hidden)'}`;
})
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>Display</main>
<button>Toggle Angle Display (Hidden)</button>
```